# Getting Attribute Inside Linq "Where" using string

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I am trying to pass a list of strings that contain fields that need to filtered.

```cs
string[] filterList = {"CostCenterId", "Description", ....}
```

Object Definition:

```cs
public class CostCenter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CostCenterId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Instead of doing:

```cs
var filterData = data
  .Where(x => x.CostCenterId.Contains(request.Filter) || x.Description.Contains(request.Filter));
```

Is it possible to get an attribute inside the lambda expression: `Where()` by passing in a `string` instead?

Is it possible to do something like:

```cs
var filterData = data
  .Where(x => x["CostCenterId"].Contains(request.Filter) || x.["Desription"]
  .Contains(request.Filter));
```

substituting values from the filterList:

```cs
var filterData = data
  .Where(x => x[filterList[0]].Contains(request.Filter) || x.[filterList[1]
  .Contains(request.Filter));
```

I have tried the following approach:

```cs
var filterData = data
  .Where(x => x.GetType().GetField("CostCenterId").Name.Contains(filter) || x.GetType().GetField("Description").Name.Contains(filter));
```

but this does not work,

The expected result is the filtered data. The result I'm getting right now is null, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: "this does not work" does not say much. Is this a EF/other ORM query? What error/unexpected result are you getting?

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to mention in my question that this is an EF query. The expected result is the filtered data. The result i'm getting right now is null.

Comment: Use [DynamicLinq](https://dynamic-linq.net/), unless you're doing this to make some abstraction on top of EF, like you're trying to make a general `QueryTableWhere("tablename", "columnname1", "value1", "columnname2", "value2")` type method - in which case, don't bother.. It'll only trip you up eventually, making things harder and harder with every corner case, than just writing a straight LINQ query in the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF uses `IQueryable` interface which accepts [expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) so it can analyze your code and try to translate it to actual SQL. One of the options here is to build the filter expression for `Where` clause yourself. For limited case of handling only string properties you can something like that (edge case of empty `filterList` is omitted):

```
var filterValue = "test";// request.Filter

string[] filterList = { "CostCenterId", "Description" };
var par = Expression.Parameter(typeof(CostCenter));
var stringContains = typeof(string).GetMethod(nameof(string.Contains), new[] {typeof(string)});
var predicate = filterList
    .Select(f => 
    {
        var prop = Expression.Property(par, typeof(CostCenter), f);
        return (Expression) Expression.Call(prop, stringContains, Expression.Constant(filterValue));
    })
    .Aggregate((agg,curr) => Expression.OrElse(agg,curr));
    
var filter = Expression.Lambda<Func<CostCenter, bool>>(predicate, par);
```

And then use it in the query:

```
var filterData = data.Where(filter);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have tried to implement this solution, but I seem to be getting the following error: ` 'IEnumerable<CostCenter>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Where<CostCenter>(IQueryable<CostCenter>, Expression<Func<CostCenter, bool>>)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<CostCenter>' `

This occurs when I pass the filter expression into the data.Where()

Comment: @ezennnn what is the type of `data` ?

Comment: The type of `data` is IQueryable<CostCenter>

Comment: Turns out the error was because, I had changed IQueryable<CostCenter> to IEnumerable<CostCenter>, changing it to type IQueryable resolved the issue. Thanks

Comment: @ezennnn Glad it helped. Yes, wanted to write that from your error your type is not `IQueryable` =).